# cartesian product with unordered index set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have (index) sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, and a function $f:S_1\to S_2$. I also have a family of sets $X_{s_1}$, parameterized by $s_1\in S_1$, and I want to generate a family of sets $Y_{s_2}$ parameterized by $s_2\in S_2$. In particular, I basically want $$Y_{s_2}=\prod_{s_1\in f^{-1}(s_2)}X_{s_1}.$$

However, since I don't have an ordering on $S_1$, it's not clear to me how to write down an element $y\in Y_{s_2}$. Essentially, the data in $y$ would be, for each $s_1\in f^{-1}(s_2)$, a value in $X_{s_1}$, but we can't write this canonically as a list, since there is no natural ordering on $S_1$.

How would people generally define / write what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $y\in Y_{s_2}$ is simply a function with domain $f^{-1}[\{s_2\}]$ such that $y(s_1)\in X_{s_1}$ for each $s_1\in f^{-1}[\{s_2\}]$. The usual notations for the $s_1$ coordinate of $y$ are $y(s_1)$ and $y_{s_1}$, modelled on the usual function and sequence notations; either is acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $f^{-1}[\{s_2\}]$?

Comment: @user56834: $f^{-1}[A]$ is a standard notation for the inverse image under $f$ of the set $A$. Here the set in question is the singleton $\{s_2\}$. I would write $f^{-1}(s_2)$ only if $f^{-1}$ were a function, and then it would refer to a single element of the domain of $f$, not, as here, to a subset of that domain. In short, it means the same thing as your $f^{-1}(s_2)$ but has the virtue of making a distinction between images of sets and images of points.